# Google Glass Stuck at the “Glass” screen

Tags: google-glass

My Google Glass is stuck at Glass screen and doesn't go beyond that. Can't fastboot either. The device is recognized by the Android Development Tools Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you have exhausted your normal local troubleshooting (e.g. power off device; power on by holding "on" button for 15 seconds, etc.), then your best bet is to call a Glass Guide -- 800-GLASSXE. They should be able to work you through the problem.