# My Google Glass does not start up

Tags: boot, google-glass

When I try to turn on my Glass using the Power button, the power LED turns on for a second, but then turns off. I can tell that my LCD is working because when I try plugging the charging cable in, I see the battery icon displayed on the screen. However, once I try to turn it on, it doesn't start up, even with the charging cable plugged in.

Is there a battery issue or is it something wrong with my firmware?

Note that this is different from [Google Glass Stuck at the “Glass” screen](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/65615/google-glass-stuck-at-the-glass-screen), as that question manages to make it to the Glass splash screen, but in my question, it does not even make it there.

Answer (score 3):

Offhand, it sounds like your battery is still too low a charge to actually turn on. Make sure you leave it plugged in and the LED is on or pulsing. **Do not turn it off while charging.**

If you're still having problems, your best bet is to [contact the support team](https://support.google.com/glass/answer/3079854).